# Java HashMap.remove (x) removes all instances of x, instead of just the first

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have a little sample of test code here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestCode {

    static Map <String, Integer> bob = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        bob.put ("J", 5);
        bob.put ("5", 12);
        bob.put ("gfdsa", 599);
        bob.put ("J", 2);
        bob.put ("J", 77);

        bob.remove ("J");

        // I want this to print '4', saying that it just removed the first instance of J.
        System.out.println (bob.size ()); 

    }
}
```

When this runs, however, it prints 2. This means that it removed all instances of "J". I want it to print 4, saying that it just removed the first instance of "J".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Keys are unique in a `Map`. If you add 3 `J`s as keys, there's only going to be the last mapping `J -> 2` present before you remove it.

Comment: Don't use `HashMap` for this

Comment: @Abhijith What should I use?

Comment: After you call `.put("J", value)` once, any more calls will just overwrite the "J" entry's value when using a `HashMap`.

Comment: @Demandooda a multimap

Comment: If you want to handle multi values in map, take a look at MultiMap from Guava : https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: @Abhijith That wouldn't help either. It would still remove all the values mapped to `J` from the multimap.

Comment: @Abhijith Thank you. this was all I was looking for. I do not know why I was downvoted. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Kayaman Multimap does not work?

Comment: Not the way you're hoping it would work based on your question.

Comment: @Kayaman there is a method which removes a single Key-value pair `remove(Object key, Object value)`. But OP needs to know the KV pair...

Comment: @Kayaman so what do I do?

Comment: @Abhijith Regular hashmap has something like that. I do not care about the value. Only the key.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What's the big picture? I'm sure your program does more than just add and remove values from a map.

Comment: @Demandooda There isn't any method to do what you ask in HashMap. You could create a `HashMap` with `String` (Key) and a `Queue` (Value)...you would have to create wrapper methods for `remove`/`add` operations and just `poll`/`add` from the Queue when required

Comment: @Kayaman Yes. But this is just a test. If I can make that print a four, I can do the other things. All I want to know is some logic in a map that can allow me to only access the first instance of a key. One thing I was thinking of what iterating over the hashmap, but I wanted to know if there was a built in thing first.

Comment: There is no "first instance of key". A `Map` such as `HashMap` stores key-value pairs with keys being unique. A multimap allows you to store multiple values per key, but the keys are still unique. I'm not aware of any class that would allow you to do what you're hoping for. So, now that you know it's not possible (well, it's possible, but not easily), what's the big picture? There's probably a better way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: @Kayman Its complicated. All I need in the big picture is a priority queue that takes in an object with a priority, and returns the object with the lowest   mapped priority. But Java's priority queue class only takes in numbers, so I had to develop my own.

Comment: You're wrong. What good would a priority queue be that only takes in numbers? Re-read the documentation. You'll see that `PriorityQueue` can handle all kinds of objects.

Comment: @Kayaman you are amazing. Thank you so much! =D

Comment: No problem. But this is why you should always tell what you *really* want to achieve. This question wasn't about `Maps` at all in the end.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this you need to understand, how hashmap works? please check the following link-
  http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

In short, key duplicity in hashmap is not possible. When you want to put another value for key "J" it overwrites it with the last one. Therefore, there are only 3 key value pairs in the hashmap before you remove "J". That is why size of hashmap is 2 after removing "J".

Comment: I knew that. But, what I wan to know is what I can use to achieve the result i want in a map.

Comment: Then you can use Multimaps. Google it. Below is one of the link.

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: @Demandooda you'd need to import Guava into your build system.